# SVN - http checkout issue

Tags: active-directory, svn, http, ldap

I have corrected my httpd config file after that I could able succeed the LDAP authentication

Now I am trying to checkout the files
using the following code

```
SvnClient client = new SvnClient();
SvnCheckOutArgs coArgs = new SvnCheckOutArgs();
bool isCheckedOut = client.CheckOut("http://100.21.45.12:8999/SVN/myrepo/SDT", workingCopy, coArgs);
```

I am getting the following error
OPTIONS of 'http://100.21.45.12:8999/SVN/myrepo/SDT': 200 OK (http://100.21.45.12:8999)

Please help me

Thanks in Advance
Kathiravan

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this in a high-level language?  (what is that?  .NET?)  If it's laziness (remember, it's a virtue...) so that you don't have to type in the whole command, why not just do a batch script (.bat/cmd or *nix shell)?

Besides, you're getting a return code of 200, and since that's a web server (http...), the "200 OK" is a good thing.